# A quoi correspond %20?

Tags: html

A quoi correspond %20 ? Je me pose vraiment cette question.

And in english:

What is %20?

Comment: http://translate.google.com/translate_t?hl=&ie=UTF-8&text=document&sl=en&tl=iw#auto|en|A%20quoi%20correspond%20%2520%20%3F%20Je%20me%20pose%20vraiment%20cette%20question.

Comment: Cheers Ardman, we should be able to vote up edits

Comment: URL Encoding (or: 'What are those "%20" codes in URLs?') http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Comment: Ma langue maternelle est le français, mais malgré tout, je pense qu'il faut respecter que Stack Overflow soit anglophone et poser les questions en anglais seulement.

Comment: Also guys, the right close reason for non-English questions is "too localized".

Comment: @zneak and not a real question. I wonder if the OP ever heard about google? type '%20' and the first hit is the answer. So, not a real question, I agree.

Comment: @Joris Meys Does 'easy question' equate 'not a real question'? What was asked sounds pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 6):

%20 means ASCII Code 20 (Hex), which is a blank (space), see http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 2):

It's  a space character, URL-encoded.
The `20` is the character code for the space character, in hexadecimal.  In decimal, it's 32.

---

### French:

C'est un espace, URL-encoded.
Le `20` est le code de caractère pour le caractère espace, en hexadécimal. En décimal, c'est 32.

Answer (score 1):

`%20` is the `space` character URL encoded.

Answer (score 1):

A space.

For other excape characters : http://www.december.com/html/spec/esccodes.html